# Remove Custom Tooltip on mouseout Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-api, google-visualization

I'm using a timeline google chart. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38644130/4896260), I'm trying to add functionality to remove the tooltip ONLY when the mouse moves out of the tooltip. My function below removes it successfully once but and then throws errors afterwards. In addition, im looking for it to ONLY be removed after the mouse moves out of the tooltip.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function (e) {
     if ( chart.ttclone.parentNode != null) {
         chart.ttclone.parentNode.removeChild(chart.ttclone)
     }
});
```

Below is the entire snippet. What is the correct way to do this?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'President'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'Start'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'End'
    });
    dataTable.addRows([
      ['Washington', 'test', createToolTip(), new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
      ['Adams', 'test', createToolTip(), new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      ['Jefferson', 'test', createToolTip(), new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
    ]);
    //select-handler
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e) {
      //the built-in tooltip
      var tooltip = document.querySelector('.google-visualization-tooltip:not([clone])');
      //remove previous clone when there is any
      if (chart.ttclone) {
        chart.ttclone.parentNode.removeChild(chart.ttclone)
      }
      //create a clone of the built-in tooltip
      chart.ttclone = tooltip.cloneNode(true);
      //create a custom attribute to be able to distinguish
      //built-in tooltip and clone
      chart.ttclone.setAttribute('clone', true);
      //inject clone into document
      chart.ttclone.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
      tooltip.parentNode.insertBefore(chart.ttclone, chart.tooltip);
    });

    function createToolTip() {
       var mainDiv = '<div style="z-index: 1000;">';
       var list =
            '<ul class="google-visualization-tooltip-action-list">' +
                '<li class="google-visualization-tooltip-action">' +
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;">' +
                        '<a href="mailto:test@test.com?Subject=test">Contact</a>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>';
       var endMainDiv = '</div>';
       var tooltip = mainDiv + list + endMainDiv;
       return tooltip;
    }
    
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function (e) {
            if ( chart.ttclone.parentNode != null) {
                chart.ttclone.parentNode.removeChild(chart.ttclone)
            }
        });

    chart.draw(dataTable, {tooltip: {isHtml: true }});
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```css
.google-visualization-tooltip {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  max-width: 200px !important;
}
.google-visualization-tooltip[clone] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
html,
body,
timeline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline" style="height:90%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you want to listen for `'onmouseout'` on the tooltip,
rather than the `chart`
`chart.ttclone.parentNode.addEventListener('mouseout', ...`

also -- `chart.ttclone.parentNode` seems to throw both `mouseover` & `mouseout` multiple times

which could cause an error if you try `removeChild` multiple times

instead, try `style.display = 'none'`, or something similar...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'President'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'Start'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'End'
    });
    dataTable.addRows([
      ['Washington', 'test', createToolTip(), new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
      ['Adams', 'test', createToolTip(), new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      ['Jefferson', 'test', createToolTip(), new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
    ]);
    //select-handler
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e) {
      //the built-in tooltip
      var tooltip = document.querySelector('.google-visualization-tooltip:not([clone])');
      //remove previous clone when there is any
      if (chart.ttclone) {
        chart.ttclone.parentNode.removeChild(chart.ttclone)
      }
      //create a clone of the built-in tooltip
      chart.ttclone = tooltip.cloneNode(true);
      //create a custom attribute to be able to distinguish
      //built-in tooltip and clone
      chart.ttclone.setAttribute('clone', true);
      //inject clone into document
      chart.ttclone.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
      tooltip.parentNode.insertBefore(chart.ttclone, chart.tooltip);
      chart.ttclone.parentNode.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        chart.ttclone.style.display = 'none';  
      }, false);
      chart.ttclone.parentNode.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        chart.ttclone.style.display = 'block';  
      }, false);
    });

    function createToolTip() {
      var mainDiv = '<div style="z-index: 1000;">';
      var list =
        '<ul class="google-visualization-tooltip-action-list">' +
          '<li class="google-visualization-tooltip-action">' +
            '<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;">' +
              '<a href="mailto:test@test.com?Subject=test">Contact</a>' +
            '</span>' +
          '</li>' +
        '</ul>';
      var endMainDiv = '</div>';
      var tooltip = mainDiv + list + endMainDiv;
      return tooltip;
    }

    chart.draw(dataTable, {tooltip: {isHtml: true }});
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```css
.google-visualization-tooltip {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  max-width: 200px !important;
}
.google-visualization-tooltip[clone] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
html,
body,
timeline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline" style="height:90%"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!