# lost focus tooltip from Google Visualization line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

i hope someone could help me. I have line chart with

```
tooltip: { trigger: 'both'}
```

but i have so many texts in tooltip i can't click in another point so after selected i can't hide him. It is any options what let me click anywhere and lost focus? (i need 'both' options)
For any help thanks a lot!

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38648489/5090771), the tooltip is shown when the row is clicked, then stays in place until first `mouseout` -- which you could replace with your own event...

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat i think it is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution would be to use an HTML tooltip with a div that you can limit the size of so that it doesn't take up your entire chart area. Would this work in your situation?

If you post up a specific example it would be easier to troubleshoot for you.