# Is it possible to add tooltips to google chart using only Class EmbeddedChart?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have tried to ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605363/need-tooltips-change-google-sheet-existing-data-into-datatable) where I'd use an embedded chart in gSheets to add tooltips. An answer came back that doesn't work. It DID, however, lead me to search through "google.visualization.DataTable()". This only get me more confused, as I think that creates the chart in another html page.

So, now I'm restating my question to see if what I want is even possible.

**GOAL:** Have a chart in existing gSheet use custom tooltips from another column like these [nifty, dynamic tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content)

**PROBLEMS/MY DEFICIENCIES:**

1) Many examples on StackOverflow show adding the data in the code itself.  [Here's one using addTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647281/remove-custom-tooltip-on-mouseout-google-chart?r=SearchResults) I need to use the data in my sheet and I don't know how to reference/call it.

2) Most guides in Google use depreciated Uiapp service , and I can't figure out how to copy/learn their code to translate to the new HTML service. [Github example](https://github.com/gkaldev/charts-in-apps-script/blob/master/GoogleFormsVisualizer.gs)

3) If I was to try to use google.visualization.DataTable, it gives me an error, making me think that it wants a more code, and other html files. I can't find the tutorials on HOW to do this. I'm willing to try but can't find the right search terms.

4) Is there a better way to do this? All videos/articles show from 2014 and older.

My code:

```
  function addNewRange) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q:Q').activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var chart = charts[0];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asScatterChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('S3:S50004'))
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('T3:S50004'))
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('Q3:Q50004')) // This the line I need to use as the tooltips
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', false)
  .setPosition(2, 7, 0, 0)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```